# A Hotwheels Problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, everyday-life, free-body-diagram, centrifugal-force

I have a Hotwheels track set. It has a looped structure such that at some point in the car's trajectory, it becomes upside down. But in such a situation, it doesn't fall to the ground. I understand this has something to do with its fast speed. Can someone please explain as to why exactly this happens? Why it doesn't fall down?

[image]
Something like this. (arrow indicates the position I was talking about)

I was wondering what kind of forces were acting on the car at that point. A theory based (and not mathematical) explanation would be helpful since I am not accustomed with mathematical explanations

Comment: The car keeps running into the track because the track is more sharply curved than the parabola the car would describe if it were a free projectile. It may help to reframe the problem so that you start the car stationary at the top of the loop, but the loop itself is translating rapidly from right to left.